# How does one use python OpenCV to open 16 bit 1 channel gray scale image

Tags: python, opencv

How does one use OpenCV to open 16 bit 1 channel gray scale image? I do not want to convert the file. The file is already in the form I need it.

```
In [62]: image = cv2.imread(file, -1)

In [63]: image.dtype
Out[63]: dtype('uint8')

In [64]: image.shape
Out[64]: (1280, 960, 3)     # 3 channels of uint8

In [76]: image.size
Out[76]: 3686400

===========================================

In [65]: image = cv2.imread(file, 0)

In [66]: image.dtype
Out[66]: dtype('uint8')

In [67]: image.shape
Out[67]: (1280, 960)       # one channel of uint8

In [74]: image.size
Out[74]: 1228800
===========================================

In [69]: image = cv2.imread(file, 1)

In [70]: image.dtype
Out[70]: dtype('uint8')

In [71]: image.shape
Out[71]: (1280, 960, 3)        # 3 channels of uint8

In [72]: image.size
Out[72]: 3686400
```

I am expecting 1 channel of uint16 and the file size should be 2457600

Comment: What format is the image in? If it's flat binary, `numpy.fromfile` and slice it into desired shape.

Comment: That approach does load the image as 16 bit values.. I can either manipulate the array and remove the header etc... but I would like to keep the image format... eg..1280x960, 16 bit gray scale, relative position of pixels etc.. without more manipulation if possible. Possible?

Comment: That depends. What format is the image in (or, if you don't know, what program produced the image?)